# Android ListView: how to set last visible item by index?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

I have an Android `ListView`, and want to scroll to a specific position. Using `list.SetSelection(index)` or `list.SmoothScrollToPosition(index)` does almost what I need.

But suppose I have a very long list (much longer than will fit on the screen), and I pick an index somewhere in the middle. Both of the above methods will scroll the list such that the item specified by `index` is at the top of the page. I want to scroll such that the item specified by `index` is at the *bottom* of the page.

The best I've come up with so far is an ugly kludge where I wait for the `ListView`'s layout to finish, measure the height of the list and the height of my item, then use `list.SmoothScrollToPositionFromTop()`, thus:

```
list.LayoutChange += (sender, evt) => {
   list.SmoothScrollToPositionFromTop(index, list.Height - list.GetChildAt(0).Height);
};
```

Note that all my rows are the same height, so I don't have to worry about getting the height of a specific child.

Also note that I'm using Xamarin.Android, so my event handler syntax is a little different than what you'd using in a plain old Java app.

While the above demonstrably works, it seems like there has to be a cleaner, clearer, less brittle, more maintainable way to do this...

Comment: Do you want your `ListView` scroll to the last position at the first?

Comment: RecyclerView might be a better option for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Joe Lv: I want my <code>ListView</code> to scroll such that an arbitrary element (whose index I know) is at the last visible position. Kevin: I know about RecyclerView; it is considerably more complex to use, and it isn't clear to me how using it would solve this problem.